# jquery/backbone/mustache/json rendering html as text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, backbone.js

soo tired and I know I've seen this before but Google's not helping I'm making a single-page backbone powered WP theme. The data is just the wordpress JSON API data & I've happily used backbone on a few projects now but this time its not playing nice.. It's doing this (showing html tags instead of.. well using them):

[image]

here's the render code:

```
this.template = '<div class="post-list">{{#posts}}<article><h2>{{title}}</h2><span class="postcontent">{{content}}</span></article>{{/posts}}</div>';

            if(this.model.get("rawdata").posts!=undefined && this.model.get("rawdata").posts.length>0)
            {
                var posts = [];
                for(i=0;i<this.model.get("rawdata").posts.length;i++)
                {
                    posts[i] = new PostModel(this.model.get("rawdata").posts[i]);
                }
                this.postCollection = new PostCollection(posts);
                this.htm = Mustache.render(this.template,this.model.get("rawdata"));
                this.$el.empty().html(this.htm);
                log(this.htm)           
            }
            else
            {
                //handle no-data result error
            }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try putting & before the variable name in the template

```
{{& posts}}
```

or

```
{{& title}}
```

It's all in the [documentation](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html)

Comment: nice!.. never seen that before great tip... I can go to bed now!... thanks

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use triple mustaches:

```
{{{title}}}
```

It's in the [documentation](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) too. This option works in [Nustache](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache) as well.